# Trouble consuming html source in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm trying to replicate the WhateverOrigin service, seen here:

http://stackshare-importer.herokuapp.com/get_website?url=http://firebase.com

---

However when I try to run it on my browser this code which worked perfectly on WhateverOrigin no longer works with my dummy service:

```
$.getJSON("http://stackshare-importer.herokuapp.com/get_website?url=" + import_url + "&callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

[image]

I just want to work with the html source string, how can I achieve this?

---

Edit:

Also tried this and get the same result:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://stackshare-importer.herokuapp.com/get_website?url=" + import_url + "&callback=?",
  jsonp: "callback",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: don't use .getJSON then. You're telling jquery to expect a JSON string, and then trying to stuff in html. That's literally not possible. An html document will NEVER conform to json syntax requirements.

Comment: @MarcB: Please see edit, still getting the same result without using getJSON.

Comment: don't use jsonp either. jsonp is json wrapped in a JS function call. Unless the server's set up to support jsonp, this won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites like WhateverOrigin and AnyOrigin get the page you want and convert it to a JSON/JSONP object, which allows it to be used cross-origin.

If you are trying to replicate what those websites are doing, you will need to create a PHP script which gets the page as a variable and then converts it to JSON and outputs it in a JSONP object.

**Change the PHP on your page "get_website" to:**

```
<?php

    $page = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
    echo 'jsonCallback({"html":'.json_encode($page, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_QUOT).'});';

?>
```

**Then use this HTML/JS on any site to output the JSON:**

```
<div class="stuffhere"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("document").ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://stackshare-importer.herokuapp.com/get_website?url=http://firebase.com',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            alert(json.html);
            $("div.stuffhere").html(json.html);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**..and it will work!**